# numpy array where each element is the sum of all elements in row until 0 is reached

Tags: numpy

I have a 2D numpy array of zeros and ones. I need to compute the sum for each element starting from this element until a zero is reached. I need one array for summing column wise, and another array for summing row wise. Below is an example, but real arrays are huge since they are binary images. I hope to do this without loops.

```
inp = [[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]]

col = mysum_cols(inp)

col = [[0, 3, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1],
       [2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [3, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1]]

row = mysum_rows(inp)

row = [[0, 3, 1, 1, 0, 3, 1, 0, 1],
       [2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: It's not immediately clear to me what the rules are. I don't understand why a 3 follows a 0.

Comment: I am moving left to right. If element is 0, the output is 0. Else, the output at the element index is the sum starting from that index and moving right until a zero is reached. @ddejohn

Comment: Show your code with loops.  I have seen solutions to problems like this using `cumsum`, along with some sort of "reset" at the 0s.  You've added the complication of a "reverse" sum.

Comment: @hpaulj I don't have code with loops. I hope to have code without loops. As for the 'reverse sum', It shouldn't be much of a problem to reverse the array and then reverse the result if this would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can indeed be done using some cumsum trickery. If you're willing to accept pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

inp = [[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]]

def do_sum(series):
    groups = series.rsub(1).cumsum()
    return series.groupby(groups).cumsum()

df = pd.DataFrame(inp).iloc[::-1, ::-1]

col = df.apply(do_sum, axis=1).iloc[::-1, ::-1].to_numpy()
row = df.apply(do_sum, axis=0).iloc[::-1, ::-1].to_numpy()
```